# Quitar el overwrite para siempre

Tags: android-studio

Como puedo quitar el overwrite. Se que si le doy a insert se quita. Pero casa minuto se vuelve a activar el overwrite. Por favor, alguien me podría ayudar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Aquí un tutorial de cómo hacerlo fácilmente: https://imgur.com/a/vWKHsOV . Ya fuera de bromas, aquí dan una posible solución desactivando el plugin de vim, mira a ver si te sirve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598930/android-studio-cursor-changing-itself-to-overwrite-mode